# Object Creation of class which is of base class or child class?

Tags: java

Can you guys explain about this:

```
ClassName.className ref=new ClassName.className(String id);
```

Note:
ClassName is the base class
className is a class that extends ClassName

My question is which class object is going to be created(ClassName=Base class or className=child Class)?

Comment: these don't seem like "child classes", but rather nested classes.

Comment: Ok fine now that code will cretae the object of the innecr class right?

Comment: yes. that's the class of which you call the constructor

Comment: And the instance(Reference variable) will hold the inncer class object right ?

Comment: how on earth should we be able to know? It's either true or false

Comment: thanks got it now , i googled it